# Adding code via addEventListener without loop by mouseover

Tags: javascript

I want to add some code by `addEventListener`. I would use `DOMContentLoaded`, but ID which I'm trying to select is not available on page load. I could use `mouseover`, but it iterate the code on any move. I could also use `click` event, but I don't want it show on click, but just when it's shown. How can I handle it?

```
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
  document.querySelector("#id").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div>asd</div>');
});
```

Comment: Is jQuery an acceptable option for you on this project?

Comment: @jasonB if so he wouldve added the [jquery] tag

Comment: It is acceptable.

Comment: @JonasW. - Obviously not. servitus, as TJBlackman pointed out below, it would be easier to help you if you added more detail to the question. I like his response, you can use delegated event handlers like gurvinder372 very easily in jQuery, https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ but there may an even better solution.

Comment: @jasonB `Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.` the description of the javascript tag

Comment: @JonasW. Zero - The number of times servitus read the tag description before adding it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **delegate**

```
var yourSpecificId = "some-id";

document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
  if (event.target.id == yourSpecificId ) //only when the id of the mouseover element is matching yourSpecificId 
  {
     //code you want to execute 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest  a `Mutation Observer`. It looks hard to implement, but it's very easy. You can provide a callback function, and then a quick `if` statement to check if the newly added element has the correct `id`. If so, run your code and disconnect the observer.

It would be easier to help you if you posted a working example of when an element is added and the function you need to run.

Read this blog: https://davidwalsh.name/mutationobserver-api